# How can I simulate Make's targets within a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, make

In working towards resolving https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160685/17423, I'm looking to create a batch-file version of [this `makefile`](https://github.com/vermiculus/playtex/blob/3e339d86c9906d2d93002df967cb74d93c2d3614/makefile).

Is there a clear/conventional way to simulate the 'target' functionality of Make?
I don't need the fancy dependency resolution `make` provides—just some sort of (hopefully clean) syntax.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use Make?

Comment: @jdigital I can't assume it will be installed; I'm distributing a couple LaTeX packages to my classmates---some of whom are computer-mostly-frightened math majors.  It will be all I can do to get them to open up the terminal; installing Cygwin/MinGW/MSYS is unfortunately out-of-the-question.

Comment: the makefile looks trivial; in fact, it is almost like a batch file.  why don't you give it a try and then if you have a problem, post a more specific question.

Comment: @jdigital the point is that I *could* do it with a really nasty if–then sequence, comparing the first command-line argument against some constant.  My question is specifically asking for a cleaner, idiomatic syntax.

Comment: That could be challenging.  Note that if one line in an action fails, Make will not execute the remaining lines.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly. Did you mean something like [this](http://pastebin.com/4vyf8agd)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the windows equivalents of the commands that you're using, but this is a simple example of running certain functions based on command line parameters. You can replace the `echo` commands with any commands that you want. If you take out the `goto :end` on line 5, the `default` function will be run when no parameters are provided, similarly to makefiles.

```
@ECHO off    
if /I %1 == default goto :default
if /I %1 == install goto :install
if /I %1 == tikzpgf goto :tikzpgf
if /I %1 == clean goto :clean

goto :eof ::can be ommited to run the `default` function similarly to makefiles

:default
echo DEFAULT
goto :eof

:install
echo INSTALL
goto :eof

:tikzpgf
echo TIKZPGF
goto :eof

:clean
echo CLEAN
goto :eof
```

Comment: The batch script should ignore case (`if /i`), to avoid failing when someone uses "INSTALL" or "clEAN," etc. Also, you could rely on the built-in `EOF` label rather then defining a new one.

Comment: Updated script with those changes